# LibGdx update with deltatime is not precise

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm new in creating game.
I have several boxes that move from top to bottom of screen and i need to make 1 unit distance between them. 
Every thing works fine except the distance is not precise and i think the deltatime cause this problem 
This is how i move the boxes :
    objX -= deltatime * speed;

**Update**

```
time += deltatime :if(time >= 3.0f) spawn
```

Im using libgdx

Comment: Are you using `Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()`?

Comment: @EthanBar yes I've used that, but distance will change randomly, in unity3d i put in fixedupdate to be precise but in gdx i don't know how fix it

Comment: @EthanBar btw i use this to spawn box: time += delta; if(time >= 3.0f) spawn

Comment: @newuser what is delta ?

Comment: @AbhishekAryan deltatime

Comment: Is it `Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()` ?

Comment: @AbhishekAryan yes

Comment: Try to use `Gdx.graphics.getRawDeltaTime ()`

Comment: @AbhishekAryan I'm already using it.

Comment: `DeltaTime` or `RawDeltaTime` ?

Comment: @AbhishekAryan Deltatime

Comment: use `RawDeltaTime`, it is time span between the current frame and the last frame in seconds, without smoothing.

Comment: @AbhishekAryan for spawn the boxes only right?  Cause im using it for moving them also

Comment: if spawning of rect is periodic then why don't you schedule a task

Comment: @AbhishekAryan can you refer me to an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of struggling i came up with an idea which is
instead of moving boxes and spawning them by `deltatime` , make boxes static and move camera over them!

So i just move camera here

```
    public void render(float delta) {
    posCameraDesired.y += 2000.0f * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    guiCam.position.lerp(posCameraDesired, 0.1f);
    SemiRender();
}
```

and i have static `Y` that i'll update after each spawn 
   `lastY = 10 + lastY + ((width / 4) / 2) * 3;`
and some other logic to recycle them when they passed the `viewport`.
and every one is happy!

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule your task in this way :

```
Array<Sprite> sprites;
Texture texture;
SpriteBatch batch;
float speed=35;

@Override
public void create() {

   sprites=new Array<Sprite>();
   texture=new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
   batch=new SpriteBatch();

   Timer.instance().scheduleTask(new Timer.Task() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                spawn();
            }
        },1,2);
}

private void spawn(){
    Sprite sprite=new Sprite(texture);
    sprite.setSize(50,50);
    sprite.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2,0);
    sprites.add(sprite);
}

@Override
public void render() {

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    float delta=Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    batch.begin();
    for (Sprite sprite:sprites){
        sprite.setY(sprite.getY()+delta*speed);
        sprite.draw(batch);
    }
    batch.end();
}
```

Comment: i just tried exactly with speed=1000 ,delaySeconds=0.0f ,Interval=0.3f and still its like a cycle each 3 or 4 spawn puts more distance between them